# How can I concatenate functions output?

Tags: php, syntax

The task is obtain this:

```
Nel mezzo del cammin 
di nostra vita
```

from this:

```
  nel-MEZzo---del-cammin, <strong>BRAKELINE</strong>di nostra-vita.
```

I'm really sick about this syntax:

```
function custom_function($v){
return str_replace("BRAKELINE","\n",$v);
}

$SRC = '  nel-MEZzo---del-cammin, <strong>BRAKELINE</strong>di nostra-vita. ';
$v = ucfirst(trim(strtolower(custom_function(preg_replace('/[^\w]+/',"\040",strip_tags($SRC))))));
echo $v;
```

and I tried something new:

```
function ifuncs($argv=NULL,$funcs=array()){
 foreach($funcs as $func){
    $argv = $func($argv);
 }
 return $argv;
}

$SRC = '  nel-MEZzo---del-cammin, <strong>BRAKELINE</strong>di nostra-vita. ';
$v = ifuncs(
$SRC,
array(
    'strip_tags',
    'f1' => function($v){ return preg_replace('/[^\w]+/',"\040",$v); },
    'f2' => function($v){
        return str_replace("BRAKELINE","\n",$v);
    },
    'strtolower',
    'trim',
    'ucfirst'
)

);
echo $v;
```

It's works very well, but I would to know if there is a better way (aka existing library) to do this.

Answer (score 3):

What you have written is how [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce) works:

```
$fns = array(
    'strip_tags',
    function($v) {
        return preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', ' ', $v);
    },
    function($v) {
        return str_replace('BRAKELINE', "\n", $v);
    },
    'strtolower',
    'trim',
    'ucfirst',
);

$input = '  nel-MEZzo---del-cammin, <strong>BRAKELINE</strong>di nostra-vita. ';

$v = array_reduce($fns, function($result, $fn) {
  return $fn($result);
}, $input));
```

Applied to your current function:

```
function ifuncs(array $funcs, $input = null) 
{
    return array_reduce($funcs, function($result, $fn) {
        return $fn($result);
    }, $input));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No shorter, but quite more elegant.

```
function fns($input=NULL,$fns=array()){
   $input = array_reduce($fns, function($result, $fn) {
     return $fn($result);
   }, $input);
   return $input;
}
```